# How do I get Pagination to Work?

Tags: templating, pagination

I thought this would be easy.  I cut and pasted code that works from the Mijingo Happy Lager tutorial site. But, I keep getting the template error below.

My code...

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('posts').limit(8) as postEntries %}

    {% for post in postEntries %}

        <div class="element-item {{post.isotope}} box col-md-3 ">
            <div class="post-box vertical clearfix">
                <a href="{{ post.url }}" class="image-link arrow-icon dark-overlay"><img src="{{ post.postImage.first().getUrl('thumbImage')}}" width="434" height="434" alt=""></a>

                <div class="extra-info">                                    
                    <h5><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title}}</a></h5>

                    <p class="meta small">{{ post.postDate | date('F d, Y') }}</p>
                    <a href="{{post.url}}" class="go-to-arrow"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="pagination">
        <ul>
            {% if paginate.prevUrl %}
                <li><a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}" class="pag-prev-link">Previous Page</a></li>
            {% endif %}

            {% for page, url in paginate.getPreviousUrls(5) %}
                <li><a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}

            <li class="current">{{ paginate.currentPage }}</li>

            {% for page, url in paginate.getNextUrls(5) %}
                <li><a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}

            {% if paginate.nextUrl %}
                <li><a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}" class="pag-next-link">Next Page</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>

{% endpaginate %}
```

The error message...

> Neither the property "getPreviousUrls" nor one of the methods "getPreviousUrls()", "getgetPreviousUrls()"/"isgetPreviousUrls()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Craft\PaginateVariable"

What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the Mijingo tutorial, but pretty sure you need to change this:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('posts').limit(8) as postEntries %}
```

To this:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('posts').limit(8) as paginate, postEntries %}
```

If that doesn't work, then there is probably a conflict with your using `paginate` as a variable inside the `{% paginate %}` tag.

You should update it to be something else like the example in the [pagination docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/paginate).

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: But the pagination docs approach works.  Good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of years later, I ran into the same issue. In case there are others looking, it looks like this line:

```
{% for page, url in paginate.getPreviousUrls(5) %}
```

Should be:

```
{% for page, url in paginate.getPrevUrls(5) %}
```